# As an exercise, rewrite this function so that it doesn't contain any loops?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner in python, reading a book, I really couldn't come across an answer with this exercise it is using modifier functions for adding time in object attributes.

```
def increment(time,seconds):
    time.seconds = time.seconds + seconds
    while time.seconds >= 60:
        time.seconds = time.seconds - 60
        time.minutes = time.minutes + 1
    while time.minutes >= 60:
        time.minutes = time.minutes - 60
        time.hours = time.hours + 1
```

Comment: Hint: use `/` and `%`.

Comment: Just as multiplication is repeated addition ... repeated subtraction is integer division.

Answer (score 0):

In this exercise you are keeping seconds in valid range (0..59), then the same for minutes, for example:

1:29:15 + 10sec -> 1:29:25 -> 1:29:25

1:59:40 + 30sec -> 1:59:70 -> 1:60:10 -> 2:00:10

You can rewrite the exercise using the floor division (//) and modulus (%):

```
def increment(time,seconds):
    time.seconds = time.seconds + seconds

    time.minutes = time.minutes + (time.seconds//60)
    time.seconds = time.seconds%60
    time.hours = time.hours + (time.minutes//60)
    time.minutes = time.minutes%60
```

Comment: Hi, was this answer useful?